# ¿Hay una forma más simple de evaluar que varias variables son verdaderas en PHP?

Tags: php

Si tengo muchas variables y quiero verificar que **todas son verdaderas** suelo hacer esto:

```
if ($aData && $bData && $cData && $nData ){
    echo "Todas verdaderas";
}else{
    echo "Al menos una falsa";
}
```

Me pregunto si hay alguna forma más simple de evaluar esto. Imaginemos que son 20 variables y no quiero hacer 20 veces `&&`.

¿Habría una forma más simple de hacer esta evaluación?

---

#### Ejemplo de contexto de uso

Un contexto en el que se usa mucho sería por ejemplo una serie de datos que son enviados por POST desde un formulario.

Yo recupero las variables en un ternario y luego debo evaluar que todas tengan datos para hacer entonces procedimientos con cada variable como inserción en una base de datos o algo así:

```
$aData = ( empty($_POST["aData"]) ) ? NULL : $_POST["aData"];
$bData = ( empty($_POST["bData"]) ) ? NULL : $_POST["bData"];
$cData = ( empty($_POST["cData"]) ) ? NULL : $_POST["cData"];
$nData = ( empty($_POST["nData"]) ) ? NULL : $_POST["nData"];
```

Comment: haciendo uso de `isset()` y pasando múltiples argumentos no te sirve?

Comment: Creo que `PHP` no cuenta una función como tal, lo que se pudiera hacer es guardar todas las variables en un `array` y usar la función `in_array`, no se me viene a la mente alguna otra opción por ahora.

Comment: @element no. De hecho, yo prefiero `empty`  a `isset`, por ejemplo para recuperar variables por POST. Pero no veo cómo hacer lo de *pasar múltiples argumentos* ¿? La idea es disponer de las variables como entes individuales pero evaluar si todas tienen datos de una forma fácil.

Comment: entiendo @A.Cedano solo se me ocurrió esto, pero lo dejo como comentario `$valOne;

$valTwo = "Adios";

foreach(array($valOne, $valTwo) as $element){
 if(!empty($element)){
  echo "Valores llenos";
 }else{
  echo "valores sin llenar";
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
$variables = array($_POST["aData"],$_POST["bData"],$_POST["cData"],$_POST["nData"]);
$no_variables=count($variables);
$booleano=true;
for($i=0;$i<$no_variables;$i++){
    $booleano=$booleano && boolval(isset($variables[$i]));
}
if($booleano){
    echo "Todas verdaderas";
}else{
    echo "Al menos una falsa";
}
```

También prueba cambiando la variable `$booleano` a `false` y el `&&` por `||` y combinaciones de eso, pero ya depende de la logica que le quieras meter a tu programa. Puedes hacer lo mismo con `empty`.

Comment: Gracias. Probaré tu código a ver qué tal... Dado que `$_POST`  es un array entonces podría probar directamente sobre él y buscar la forma al mismo tiempo de guardar cada dato en una variable, para poder usar dichas variables en caso de necesitarlas para otra operación como un `INSERT` en la base de datos. Estoy buscando simplicidad en el código.

Comment: De echo lo hice asi, por que los indices de `$_POST` son nombrados y entonces no podrias usar la variable `$i`. En ese caso convendria un foreach como dice @element

Comment: También puedes meter un `if($booleano){break;}` dentro del `for` para terminar a la primera ocurrencia de un `false`.